# pandas groupby on multiindex levels: group_keys

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame whose columns are MultiIndex.
I want to groupby one level of the columns and use apply to perform a transformations.

**Goal: I want that the DataFrame passed to the function using apply does *not* have the keys of groupby in the index.**

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) it looks like this is what `group_keys` is doing, but it seems to have no effect:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 5)),
        'B': pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 5)),
        'C': pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 5))}

data = pd.concat(data, axis=1, names=['feat_1', 'feat_2'])

def foo(df):
    print(df.columns)
    return df.sum(1)
```

My attempt:

```
result = data.groupby(level=['feat_1'], axis=1, group_keys=False).apply(foo)
```

This is what is printed on screen:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
           names=['feat_1', 'feat_2'])
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
           labels=[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
           names=['feat_1', 'feat_2'])
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
           labels=[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
           names=['feat_1', 'feat_2'])
```

Desired output of print: I would like the function `foo`to receive a dataframe with only `feat_2` as columns, given I am using `group_keys=False`

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Am I missing something from the documentation? Or how can I achieve what I want (possibly without modifying the function foo)?

Note: I am using pandas 0.20.3 on Python 3

Comment: Just the columns headers. The foo function prints the dataframe columns, which is the relevant part for me.  The sum operation is just a place-holder to make the function run.

Comment: Is desired output describing what should be printed? Why you only want to print 1,2 ,3, 4? What about 0s? What is the usage of ignoring it?

Comment: edited: hopefully is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Rather than grouping, how about:

```
for feat1 in data.columns.levels[0]:
    print(list(data.columns.levels[1]))

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: The loop gets quite messy as I have more levels...plus the goal is not printing/retrieving the columns, but to have a dataframe with only one level of columns passed to the function in groupby